# Is it ok to restart browser between specs in Integration Tests?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

We have number or Protractor/Jasmine specs for our AngularJS-based project. Is it ok to do:

```
afterAll(function(){
   browser.restart();
}
```

to clean up things between specs?

Comment: What exactly are you cleaning up? Please elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The reality is that I have issue with promises timeout. It can be so that we already 20 minutes in future comparing with the time of starting tests and then there is an error because of promises timeout from the first spec. So as a shortcut (till I will not find the real issue with promises) I want to just restart browser after each spec. I understand that it is a wrong approach in general, but want to use it as a temporary solution. What makes me confuses is that in general test are working correctly even having this promises timeout issue...

Comment: Thank you, I think it is pretty much okay to have this temporary solution. In general though, it sounds like you might have a problem with one test affecting the subsequent tests..may be you should try reorganizing them so that they don't have an impact on each other..sorry for the broad manner of answering - difficult to imagine without actually seeing the real picture. Let me know if you would need help understanding what is going on with the timeouts.

Comment: Will do. Thank you. By the way, does Protractor somehow waits automatically for all promises in test (and in Spec) to be resolved before it goes to the next test (or Spec)?

Comment: Yes, it should. There is the [Control Flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md) in action that maintains a queue of promises to be resolved.

Comment: Then how it can be so that I'm getting promises timeout error for the test from the first spec during one of the next specs?

Comment: This is use-case specific, there is no generic answer. Please consider creating a new question with details and I'll also take a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is a built-in setting - `restartBrowserBetweenTests`:

```
// If true, protractor will restart the browser between each test.
// CAUTION: This will cause your tests to slow down drastically.
restartBrowserBetweenTests: false,
```

As it says in the comment - this leads to slowing down your tests - make sure there is a *real reason* to restart the browser between tests. Note that the setting means *restarting browser with each `it()`*,  not `describe()`.

Note that [internally `restart()`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/167038499aacfd5def03472f9f548529b273e1e0#diff-b3b53682a18f203ac8d29b0e277cad26R278) forks an existing driver instance, quits the current driver and reinitializes all the globals - `browser`, `element`, `$` etc.

There could be different needs to restart the browser/driver in between of the tests - for instance, previously created cookies would be completely lost/removed. For instance, this may allow not logging out explicitly after each test to save time (not sure if this is good in general).

---

> So as a shortcut (till I will not find the real issue with promises) I want to just restart browser after each spec. I understand that it is a wrong approach in general, but want to use it as a temporary solution.

As a temporary solution in your case, to enforce test isolation, I think it's okay to restart the browser after every test suite. But, make sure you don't share any variables through the globally available `browser` object - in every test, you'll get a brand new `browser`.

---

By the way, you may also try enforcing the browser's private/incognito mode:

```
multiCapabilities: [
    {
        browserName: "chrome",
        chromeOptions: {
            args: ["incognito", "disable-extensions"]
        },
     }
],
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But in the case I'm talking about - it is not about restarting between tests, but between each spec with number of tests. What do you think about it?

Comment: @ArtemVorobyev yup, updated the answer. Hope that helps.